# How could you kill yourself with a headshot?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

In CSGO, you can do actions that will provoke your own death (mostly by grenades, or by falling too high)

But then I find this on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/GlobalOffensive/comments/83wlce/bot_yogi_took_the_easy_way_out/):

[image: Suicide by headshot]

This doesn't make sense. Grenades can't headshot. So how can you kill yourself with a headshot?

Comment: The kill feed almost certainly does not describe what actually happened. My best guess is that this was on competitive mirage, and that the bot took headshot damage before being replaced by an actual player, during warm-up.

Comment: Or the bot took a headshot by another bot who got replaced by a player. Since the "weapon" image is a skull it was no regular kill, that's for sure.

Comment: Do you have a link to the reddit thread?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder [The link](https://www.reddit.com/r/GlobalOffensive/comments/83wlce/bot_yogi_took_the_easy_way_out/) is in that Imgur post under the title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this was answered in the original Reddit thread- OP posted this answer to a similar question posed by [u/Redzonefresh](https://www.reddit.com/r/GlobalOffensive/comments/83wlce/bot_yogi_took_the_easy_way_out/dvld4bc)

> Well, it's easy. You have to get a gun and put it up t...
>
> No but seriously, I just joined the match in the warmup, and I think someone
> joined and that killed/disconnected the bot that shot Yogi and it just
> appeared as suicide (just like when you kill someone and instanly get banned,
> it just shows that you killed yourself). And the headshot is because Yogi died by a headshot